# Solamente me imprime el modulo pero no la variable

Tags: python, python-3.7

Si me imprime el modulo que puse, pero no me imprime la variable que puse en el código, además en un anterior ejercicio del libro, si logran imprimir tanto el modulo como la variable. Pero también recalco que en el anterior ejercicio no usaba for, así que no se si eso es la causa que la variable no funcione, además cuando pongo la variable en el modulo si imprime las 2, tanto el modulo como la variable. Para así que quiero saber si solamente se puede imprimir ambas, si están en el modulo o no. Acá dejo el código:

Código 1

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

def imprime_datos(nombre, **datos):
  print("Datos de " + nombre)

  for clave in datos:
    print(clave + ": " + datos[clave])

imprime_datos("Pablo", edad = "mucha", estado = "enloquecido", guapo = "no")
input()
```

Código 2:

```
 #!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import argumentos

variable = "Aca dejo el modulo:"

print(variable)

print(argumentos.imprime_Datos)

input()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que raro. 1- Guardaste los cambios en el editor antes de ejecutarlo? 2- Python 2.7 o 3.7? Tal y como usas print parece que usas 3.7. 3- Hay mejores editores de código que el bloc de notas. Te recomiendo que los pruebes.

Comment: 1 si lo guarde el módulo y el archivo que importa el módulo. 2 si uso el python 3.7 en mi PC. 3 uso más el block de notas como un tema de aprendizaje, los demás editores te señalan el error y dicen dónde te equivocaste, en el block de notas debes revisarlo y ver el error por tu cuenta, pero después cambiaré

Comment: 1- entiendo. No se me ocurre nada más entonces, por que no veo nada mal en tu código. 2- Entonces quita la etiqueta de 2.7 de la pregunta. Las etiquetas python-[versión] están pensadas para que sepamos que la respuesta debe estar en dicha versión. 3- Buena idea!

Comment: @nekordemon por favor. No edites la pregunta con la solución. Agrega por favor una respuesta. No tiene sentido una pregunta sin un problema. Si encontraste la solución, por favor, agrega una respuesta.

Comment: ya encontre la solucion.